# Prevent symbol call on require in Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, clojure-core.logic

So here is my problem,

I have a file sample.clj in namespace `abc.xyz`in which i am calling db init method directly before doing any CRUD operation.

`(db/init some-config)`

When i require this namespace `abc.xyz` in a test namespace `cdf.qpr` as `(:require [abc.xyz :refer :all])`, db is already being initialized with `some-config` but i want to initialize it with `some-other-config`.

How can i require namespace preventing call of `db/init`

Answer (score 2):

Without changing the code in namespace `abc.xyz`, in particular changing the line `(db/init some-config)`, what you ask is not possible.

A more productive approach would be to ask "How do other people handle this situation, without having a top level expression like `(db/init some-config)` in their namespaces?  I suspect most put calls like that not as top level expressions in their namespaces, but inside some init function for their entire application.